# how to download file using jquery in asp.net core?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I use this code to download file using jquery.

```
$('#dwnlod').click(function (ee) {

    e.preventDefault(); 
    var currentFile = $('#SlideContainer .actv').css('background-image').replace(/^url|[\(\)]/g, '');
    alert(currentFile)
    document.location.href = currentFile;

});
```

However, it always does nothing. the reason for this is when I remove e.preventDefault to read the URL I find it distorted.

it rather than the result from alert >>

```
"https://localhost:660066/Uploads/5c92f430-4aef-41c8-b201-853597935771.jpg"
```

it displays in a new browser tab  >>

```
https://localhost:660066/Documents/Index/"https://localhost:660066/Uploads/5c92f430-4aef-41c8-b201-853597935771.jpg"
```

I don't know if I need extra steps with asp.net core routing !!?

Comment: If you want to redirect the page, use window.location.href, not document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue is that `currentFile` returns a string that is surrounded by quotes and thus the browser is interpreting it as a relative URL (since the scheme isn't at the beginning of the string). Removing the start and end quotes if they exist should get you the behavior you are looking for.